# Adjust networkD3 link distances proportionately

Tags: r, networkd3

This is my first time visualising a network so I am unfamiliar with the networkD3 package.

With the two dataframes below, I can produce the network visualisation I want.

The only issue being that whilst the link distances and widths are proportional as desired, they are still too small meaning that the nodes overlap and cover each other too much.

I have tried to change the link distances using the parameter in the forcenetwork function using static figures but the issue then is that they are not distanced in proportion to the link value. I'm unsure how to refer to the value column and am totally unfamiliar with javascript so i'm not sure how to alter the default value for the parameter.

The "charge" variable helps slightly but does not completely solve the problem.

Is there a way to multiply the link distances by whatever is set by default so that the visualisation is proportionately more spread out?

#### links df

```
structure(list(source = c("0", "0", "8", "8", "8", "8", "8", 
"8", "8", "8", "8", "8", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
"9", "9", "9", "9", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "4", "7", "7", "7", 
"7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "7", "2", "1", "3", "6", "6", "6", "6", 
"6", "6", "6"), target = c("12", "14", "12", "20", "28", "18", 
"24", "23", "35", "29", "27", "30", "12", "20", "28", "38", "25", 
"21", "26", "14", "39", "46", "24", "17", "16", "40", "23", "35", 
"42", "29", "36", "13", "37", "32", "30", "43", "12", "20", "28", 
"14", "16", "23", "29", "44", "30", "12", "19", "20", "18", "38", 
"25", "26", "31", "24", "40", "23", "29", "15", "27", "30", "12", 
"19", "18", "38", "25", "22", "31", "24", "41", "34", "40", "29", 
"33", "12", "19", "20", "18", "38", "25", "26", "22", "24", "41", 
"47", "29", "36", "15", "30", "12", "20", "24", "16", "23", "36", 
"15", "32", "30", "12", "12", "12", "12", "25", "17", "35", "36", 
"30", "45"), value = c(4632L, 1L, 2509L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1248L, 90L, 
254L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 8464L, 556L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 11L, 38L, 2461L, 249L, 
10L, 14L, 456L, 865L, 134L, 386L, 5L, 160L, 2L, 32L, 795L, 151L, 
346L, 194L, 4L, 482L, 1L, 35L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 14L, 8L, 1640L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 10L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 18L, 1L, 1046L, 194L, 
18882L, 434L, 1L, 97L, 1L, 3698L, 821L, 1L, 50L, 143L, 70L, 2L, 
450L, 8332L, 3L, 1L, 1781L, 584L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 80L, 7L, 3363L, 
169L, 1L, 1345L, 1251L, 1L, 1L, 17L, 288L, 12L, 201L, 21L, 1L, 
980L, 7841L, 558L, 378L, 72L, 39L, 13L, 38L, 1L, 11L)), .Names = c("source", 
"target", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -107L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 
0x0000000000120788>, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

#### node df

```
structure(list(name = c("Fear", "Frontier", "Nanny", "Job", "Yard", 
"Airport", "Half Pint", "Commando", "Fast Food", "Basketball", 
"Bachelorette", "Diva", "Baggage", "College", "Octane", "Clean", 
"Sister", "Army", "Drama", "Backyard", "Pirate", "Shark", "Project", 
"Model", "Survival", "Justice", "Mom", "New York", "Jersey", 
"Ax", "Warrior", "Ancient", "Pawn", "Throttle", "The Great American", 
"Knight", "American", "Outback", "Celebrity", "Air", "Restaurant", 
"Bachelor", "Family", "Royal", "Surf", "Ulitmate", "Date", "Operation"
), size = c(4633, 7841, 980, 558, 15671, 15341, 552, 1793, 4109, 
2928, 544, 24650, 55949, 795, 2463, 203, 883, 495, 1784, 438, 
564, 11, 3699, 768, 1268, 84, 40, 1047, 39, 3388, 1744, 822, 
367, 450, 143, 272, 251, 151, 692, 249, 205, 130, 160, 4, 14, 
11, 10, 7), group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)), .Names = c("name", 
"size", "group"), row.names = c(NA, -48L), class = "data.frame")
```

#### code

```
library(networkD3)

forceNetwork(Links = catlinks, Nodes = catnode,
         Source = "source", Target = "target",
         NodeID = "name",
         Group = "group", 
         Value = "value",
         Nodesize = "size",
         charge = -600, # this helps
         zoom = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

worked it out:

square rooted the value column because the values were too far apart to look right

```
forceNetwork(Links = catlinks, Nodes = catnode,
         Source = "source", Target = "target",
         NodeID = "name",
         Group = "group", # color nodes by betweeness calculated earlier
         Value = "value",
         Nodesize = "size",
         charge = -1000,
         linkDistance = networkD3::JS("function(d) { return 5*d.value; }"), # mess with the 5 to mess with the distances
         zoom = T)
```